# How do I display my react App.Js in the HTMl file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I display my App.Js react app file in my Index.html file?"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  
    <title>React Firebase Superchat</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
   
    <script src="/src/App.js">
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

firebase.initializeApp({
  // your config
})

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const analytics = firebase.analytics();


function App() {

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>⚛️</h1>
        <SignOut />
      </header>

      <section>
        {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}
      </section>

    </div>
  );
}

function SignIn() {

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button className="sign-in" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
      <p>Do not violate the community guidelines or you will be banned for life!</p>
    </>
  )

}

function SignOut() {
  return auth.currentUser && (
    <button className="sign-out" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
  )
}


function ChatRoom() {
  const dummy = useRef();
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });

  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState('');


  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;

    await messagesRef.add({
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL
    })

    setFormValue('');
    dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }

  return (<>
    <main>

      {messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}

      <span ref={dummy}></span>

    </main>

    <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>

      <input value={formValue} onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)} placeholder="say something nice" />

      <button type="submit" disabled={!formValue}>️</button>

    </form>
  </>)
}


function ChatMessage(props) {
  const { text, uid, photoURL } = props.message;

  const messageClass = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';

  return (<>
    <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={photoURL || 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png'} />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  </>)
}


export default App;
```

I am following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQyrwxMPm88&feature=youtu.be tutorial to try and create a react chat app. I'm trying to link the App.Js file into the HTML file, but it's not working. I'm trying to link the JS in HTML script tags, but it still seems to be a blank page with no text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render it to the page somewhere, like so:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

...

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But since you're using create-react-app, that should already be inside the index.js file, unless you removed that.  Using create-react-app the App component is getting rendered on the page by default, so you shouldn't have to do anything except fill in the App component.

Comment: I put the code in my <script> tags but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I would just remake your project using create-react-app, and then don't delete the index.js file.  Just add your code to the app.js file, replacing the premade App component with yours.